what is the probability at least one "Ava" stand before the every person named "Harry"?
Given $44$ children , where $4$ of them are girls named "Ava" and $6$ of them are boys named "Harry"
you order all $44$ children in a queue.
what is the probability at least one "Ava" stand before every person named "Harry"?
my attempt:
Let's calculate the complement, find the probability that all children named "Ava" stand after all children named "Harry".
suppose we focus only on the $10$ children named "Ava" and "Harry" (ignoring the other children).
Specifically, there are $4$ children named "Ava" and $6$ children named "Harry".
The total number of ways to arrange these $10$ children in a queue is: $10!$
The only arrangement where all "Ava" stand after all "Harry" is: $HHHHHHAAAA$
The $6$ "Harry" can be arranged in $6!$ ways.
The $4$ "Ava" can be    arranged in $4!$ ways.
Therefore, the total number of favorable arrangements for the complement event is: $\frac{6! \cdot 4!}{10!}$
The probability that at least one "Ava" stands before "Harry" is the complement of the above: $ 1 - \frac{6! \cdot 4!}{10!}$
is my attempt correct?

This does not sound right to me, but that is made more difficult to know for sure what the intended question should be due to mistakes in grammar.  "...stand before the all Harry" is not correct syntax.  My initial impression reading the question and my brain trying to autocorrect the grammar is that the intended question was to be to ask the probability that at least one Ava stands before every person named Harry.  That happens if and only if the first person in the lineup of our ten people we are interested in is named Ava and occurs with probability $\dfrac{4}{10}$.

thank you, I have changed the syntax. you got it right with your initial impression

"The all Harry" sounds like a forgotten Norse God... maybe some distant cousin of Odin the All-Father.

@JMoravitz Perhaps the all Harry is the true, mathematical, platonic Harry, living up in the world of forms somewhere.

You ask for the probability of this event:

at least one "Ava" stand before every person named "Harry"

Here is an example of exactly one Ava standing before every person named Harry:
AHHHHHHAAA.
Another example: AHHHAHAHAH.
Exactly two persons named Ava standing before every person named Harry:
AAHHHHHHAA.
All of those are examples of at least one person named Ava standing before all the persons named Harry.
Here are some examples of the complement of the event 'at least one "Ava" stand before every person named "Harry"':
HHHHHHAAAA, HHHHHAAHAA, HHHAHHHAAA, HAAAAHHHHH.
In some of these examples there is a person named Ava who stands before some person named Harry, but there is no person named Ava who stands before every person named Harry.
You counted only the first example, which is the one that is the most extremely different from the event you were originally looking for: not only is there no Ava who stands before every Harry, there is no Ava who stands before any Harry.
This is a common conceptual error. When you are looking for the complement of an event $P$, you might think of the "opposite" of $P$, in the sense of an event that is as different from $P$ as any event can possibly be. But actually the complement of $P$ includes every possible outcome that does not perfectly match the description of $P$, even if it "almost" matches the description of $P$.
For example, in HAAAAHHHHH, all of the persons named Ava stand before almost all the persons named Harry. There is just one person named Harry that all the persons named Ava do not stand before. But that's enough to say that this outcome is not part of $P$, and therefore it is part of the complement of $P$.
